# How to access embedded objects and?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a report where I pull data and want to compare it somewhere else. I can access most of the data but not the embedded stuff. I have tried to figure it out but need some help.

The below is throwing me through a loop. I want to be able to pull for example in pairs, like.

Contracted Protected Data Size (TB) and 12.0

So I get that there is a pairing but don't know how to address or access the. I know I can do something like. So... `$_.questions` gets me that data but I done know how to just pull the pairs I need.

```
'Select-Object{$_.id,$_.name,$_.backupBillableSpaceGb,$_.company.name,$_.questions}'

id                     : 20221
name                   : LANVault Backup Profile
type                   : @{id=72; name=Backup Profile; _info=}
status                 : @{id=1; name=Active; _info=}
company                : @{id=15412; identifier=ACME, INC; name=ACME;             
_info=}
contact                : @{id=40760; name=Dave ROTH; _info=}
site                   : @{id=14657; name=Main; _info=}
locationId             : 2
businessUnitId         : 10
installationDate       : 2018-04-18T00:00:00Z
warrantyExpirationDate : 2019-04-18T00:00:00Z
billFlag               : True
backupSuccesses        : 0
backupIncomplete       : 0
backupFailed           : 0
backupRestores         : 0
backupBillableSpaceGb  : 0.00
backupYear             : 0
backupMonth            : 0
questions              : {@{answerId=131586; questionId=655; 
question=Contracted Protected Data Size (TB); answer=12.0; 
sequenceNumber=1.00; numberOfDecimals=1; fieldType=Number; 
requiredFlag=True},
@{answerId=131589; questionId=656; question=Contracted # of
Protected Servers; answer=2; sequenceNumber=2.00;
numberOfDecimals=0; fieldType=Number; requiredFlag=True},
@{answerId=131591; questionId=657; question=Additional
Protected Data Cost: ($/TB/Mo.); answer=300.0;
sequenceNumber=3.00; numberOfDecimals=0; fieldType=Currency;
requiredFlag=True}, @{answerId=131592; questionId=658;
question=Additional Server Cost: ($/Server/Mo.); answer=60.0;
sequenceNumber=4.00; numberOfDecimals=0; fieldType=Currency;
requiredFlag=True}...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you have is an object, where the value of a property is an array of objects. How do you want to output this? You can use `Select-Object` to create a custom object defining properties based on the source object, or you can loop through objects in a `ForEach-Object` loop and create objects that way. I'll give examples of each.

`Select-Object` method:

```
$SourceObject | Select ID,name,backupBillableSpaceGb,@{l='CompanyName';e={$_.company.name}},@{l='Contracted Protected Data Size (TB)';e={$_.questions|Where{$_.question -eq 'Contracted Protected Data Size (TB)'}|Select -expand answer}}
```

This makes for extremely long longs, and gets really hard to read, but it does keep it all inline. In these examples I constructed properties in the `@{label='Property Name';expression={Property Value}}` format, using the shorter 'l' for 'label' and 'e' for 'expression'.

`ForEach-Object` method:

```
$SourceObject | ForEach{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID = $_.id
        Name = $_.name
        CompanyName = $_.company.name
        'Contracted Protected Data Size (TB)' = $_.questions|Where{$_.question -eq 'Contracted Protected Data Size (TB)'}|Select -expand answer
    }
    }
```

This should create the same output, but is generally easier to read. It does take up a lot more space though.

This does have some advantages though, such as: If this becomes very slow, due to having to loop through the `$_.questions` array multiple times, you could create a hashtable out of that array, and reference that, if desired.

```
$SourceObject | ForEach{
    $QuestionsHT = @{}
    $_.questions | ForEach{$QuestionsHT.Add($_.question,$_.answer)}
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID = $_.id
        Name = $_.name
        CompanyName = $_.company.name
        'Contracted Protected Data Size (TB)' = $QuestionsHT.'Contracted Protected Data Size (TB)'
        'Additional Protected Data Cost: ($/TB/Mo.)' = $QuestionsHT.'Additional Protected Data Cost: ($/TB/Mo.)'
    }
    }
```

Comment: How do I learn more about these types of objects and how to understand how to get at the data.  Is there something that will let me pipe in an object and let me see how to reference its properties?  I have been trying to learn from YouTube and sites but they are pretty basic.

Comment: The `Get-Member` cmdlet (or `GM` for short) will tell you what properties and methods an object has, and what kind of values those properties contain. That should give you some indication on how to access the properties. Some of it is just trial and error, or simply experience and recognizing formats of things.